# Fillna using multiple approaches at a time - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101,202,202,202],
                        'start_date':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM','13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM','13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM'],
                        'end_date':['5/12/2013 09:27:00 AM',np.nan,'06/11/2014 08:00:00 AM',np.nan,'12/16/2011 10:00:00','10/18/2012 00:00:00',np.nan],
                        'type':['O','I','O','O','I','O','I']})
df.start_date = pd.to_datetime(df.start_date)
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.end_date)
```

I would like to `fillna()` under the `end_date` column based on two approaches below

a) If `NA` is found in **any row except last row** of that person, `fillna` by copying the value from next row

b) If `NA` is found in the **last row of that person** `fillna` by adding 10 days to his `start_date` (because there is no next row for that person to copy from. So, we give random value of 10 days)

The rules `a` and `b` only for persons with `type=I`.

For persons with `type=O`, just fillna by copying the value from `start_date`.

This is what I tried. You can see am writing the same code line twice.

```
  df['end_date'] = np.where(df['type'].str.contains('I'),pd.DatetimeIndex(df['end_date'].bfill()),pd.DatetimeIndex(df.start_date.dt.date))
  df['end_date'] = np.where(df['type'].str.contains('I'),pd.DatetimeIndex(df['start_date'] + pd.DateOffset(10)),pd.DatetimeIndex(df.start_date.dt.date))
```

Any elegant and efficient way to write this as I have to apply this on a big data with 15 million rows?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Your expected output seems incorrect. Please check again and update the expected output accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: *If NA is found in any row except last row of that person, fillna by copying the value from next row* Are you referring the next row from the `end_date` or the `start_date` column?

Comment: next row from the `start_date` column of that specific person. Not from other person_ids.

Comment: updated the expected output

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - btw, you helped me solve a problem few weeks back. But forgot to write as an answer. If you can write an answer for the old question as well (which I believe would be in our chat window, that I am not able to access), I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: Thanks @TheGreat i will add an answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231001/discussion-between-the-great-and-shubham-sharma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

```
s1 = df.groupby('person_id')['start_date'].shift(-1)
s1 = s1.fillna(df['start_date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=10))
s1 = df['end_date'].fillna(s1)

s2 = df['end_date'].fillna(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = np.where(df['type'].eq('I'), s1, s2)
```

#### Explanations

`Group` the dataframe on `person_id` and `shift` the column `start_date` one units upwards.

```
>>> df.groupby('person_id')['start_date'].shift(-1)

0   2013-09-08 11:21:00
1   2014-06-06 08:00:00
2   2014-06-06 05:00:00
3                   NaT
4   2012-10-13 00:00:00
5   2012-12-13 11:45:00
6                   NaT
Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Fill the `NaN` values in the shifted column with the values from `start_date` column after adding an offset of `10 days`

```
>>> s1.fillna(df['start_date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=10))

0   2013-09-08 11:21:00
1   2014-06-06 08:00:00
2   2014-06-06 05:00:00
3   2014-06-16 05:00:00
4   2012-10-13 00:00:00
5   2012-12-13 11:45:00
6   2012-12-23 11:45:00
Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now fill the `NaN` values in `end_date` column with the above series `s1`

```
>>>  df['end_date'].fillna(s1)

0   2013-05-12 09:27:00
1   2014-06-06 08:00:00
2   2014-06-11 08:00:00
3   2014-06-16 05:00:00
4   2011-12-16 10:00:00
5   2012-10-18 00:00:00
6   2012-12-23 11:45:00
Name: end_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Similarly fill the `NaN` values in `end_date` column with the values from `start_date` column to create a series `s2`

```
>>> df['end_date'].fillna(df['start_date'])

0   2013-05-12 09:27:00
1   2013-09-08 11:21:00
2   2014-06-11 08:00:00
3   2014-06-06 05:00:00
4   2011-12-16 10:00:00
5   2012-10-18 00:00:00
6   2012-12-13 11:45:00
Name: end_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then use `np.where` to select the values from `s1` / `s2` based on the condition where the type is `I` or `O`

```
>>> df

   person_id          start_date            end_date type
0        101 2013-05-07 09:27:00 2013-05-12 09:27:00    O
1        101 2013-09-08 11:21:00 2014-06-06 08:00:00    I
2        101 2014-06-06 08:00:00 2014-06-11 08:00:00    O
3        101 2014-06-06 05:00:00 2014-06-06 05:00:00    O
4        202 2011-12-11 10:00:00 2011-12-16 10:00:00    I
5        202 2012-10-13 00:00:00 2012-10-18 00:00:00    O
6        202 2012-12-13 11:45:00 2012-12-23 11:45:00    I
```